# Use localPosition or position to store character's joints position?

Tags: unity

I have a character and I need to save all the joints positions, like Hip - Leftleg - Rightleg.

Should I use `transform.position` or `transform.localPosition`?

Comment: Hello, It sounds like a [XY-problem](https://xyproblem.info/) to me. Why do you need to save all the joint's positions? Generally they are included in the model file or prefab rather than being saved separately. Maybe you just need to save the position of the character root node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `localPosition` because it's the position of the child relative to its parent. The `transform.position` is not, it's relative the world position, if you want to store the joint position.